# Skew-symmetric matrices dot product condition

Tags: linear-algebra

From the [Wikipedia page on skew-symmetric matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix):

> Denote with $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The real $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ is skew-symmetric if and only if $\langle Ax, y\rangle = -\langle x, Ay\rangle$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I can't see how this follows from the definition $A^T=-A$ for skew-symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: for two real vectors $v,w$, we note that
$$
\langle v,w \rangle = v^Tw
$$
Now, consider what this means when
$$
v = Ax\\
w = y
$$
Noting that for multiplicatively compatible matrices $A,B$, we have 
$$
(AB)^T=B^TA^T
$$

Comment: Ah.. $\langle Ax,y\rangle+\langle x,Ay\rangle = 0$ iff $x^T(A^T+A)y=0$. This is obvious if $A^T+A=0$. On the other hand, we can choose $x=e_i$ and $y=e_j$ to get $A^T+A=0$. Done!

Comment: That is even better-put than the proof I expected. Good job.